# How do I make a GtkSharp app work on Windows

Tags: c#, mono

I am new at C# and mono. I just wrote a small GtkSharp program on my Ubuntu laptop and when I tried to run it on my girlfriend's windows 7 computer it just wouldn't start. So I thought it might be because she doesn't have Gtk installed. I found a site where I downloaded a Gtk installer and installed it, but the program still doesn't work.

What is the problem? I've seen the program work great on my Mac (which happens to have Mono installed) do I have to install mono on her computer?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. I solved it with Matthew's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the GtkSharp Runtime Redistributable to run your application on a Windows machine. GTK by itself does not provide GtkSharp or an appropriate CLR for your application. Try downloading from [the Mono website](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html).

Answer (score -1):

Install   mono and then try again.